# Need help in sql query to find common value in rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table like this

```
+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+       
|  1 |    A |    B |       
|  2 |    B |    D |       
+----+------+------+
```

Now my user will search with `A` and `D`. I want to give common of `A` and `D`. What should be the query?

Here the common is `B`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - what is your expected result?

Comment: My expected result is B. I have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you can do:

```
select t1.col2
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col2 = t2.col1
where t1.col1 = 'A' and t2.col2 = 'D';
```